# Error in hadoop streaming when using expr in a bash script

Tags: bash, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, vowpalwabbit

I am using Hadoop streaming for a job.

My mapper is written in bash. It makes use of the job_id.

```
mapred_job_id=`echo "$mapred_job_id" | awk -F "_" '{print $NF}'`
```

It works fine (lauching a stupid wordcound mapper operation for debuggin purposes) until I had the following line that make the job crash:

```
mapred_job_id=`expr $mapred_job_id \* 2`
```

The error is:

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1432766867252_0019_m_000007_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 2
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:543)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)
```

etc.

Any idea why it doesn't work? Directly at the command line it does. I also tried to use another variable with the name dummy. Same error.

Nb: This line is because there should be later on another job in the mapper that needs to get an id and cannot conflit with the ids of the previous jobs. I'm trying to get vowpal wabbit cluster implementation that works with allreduce.

Comment: Why would you double the job ID? I'm not following what you're hoping to achieve with that..

Comment: I think it has to do with vowpalwabbit implementation of allreduce. There is a daemon (spanning tree) that is listening to all the nodes and identifies them with ids. But since two jobs with two different results are produced by a mapper, I understand that is why you need to do this. Their implementation is on github: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/cluster/runvw-yarn.sh

Comment: Actually, it's weird. I misread before. They actually count the number of fields in the mapred_job_id... I don't get that, it contradicts my understanding.

Comment: A little explanation of would help.  Why are you doubling job id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. The bash script was not able to get Hadoop streaming environment variables with the command:

```
mapper=`printenv mapred_task_id'
```

or directly by calling for instance

```
$mapreduce_output_fileoutputformat_outputdir
```

as it was done in the scripts for Vowpal Wabbit cluster directory found on github.
I got around the problem by writing a python script that can get these variables using `os.environ`. `os.environ` returns a dictionary that contains all the environment variables of Hadoop streaming. It was very useful since the name of the variables has changed between the various versions of mapreduce. The dictionary provided by Cloudera was inconsistent with my own version. Here is the script that got the variables I needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import subprocess

nmappers=os.environ["mapreduce_job_maps"]
submit_host=os.environ["mapreduce_job_submithostname"]
output_dir=os.environ["mapreduce_output_fileoutputformat_outputdir"]
mapred_job_id=os.environ["mapreduce_job_id"].split("_")[-1]
mapper=os.environ["mapreduce_task_id"].split("_")[4]

print nmappers, submit_host, output_dir, mapred_job_id, mapper
```

Calling this script from the mapper written in bash, I can then use the command:

```
mapred_job_id=`expr $mapred_job_id \* 2`
```

that changes the job id as needed for the parallelization of vowpal wabbit implemented by John Langford (see https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/cluster/).